# How to pass a function as the value to jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Why isn't this working? How should one pass a function as the value here?

```
<div class="div" data-foo="50"></div>
<div class="div" data-foo="100"></div>

$('.div').animate({ 
    width: function() {
        return $(this).data('foo');
    }
}, 500);
```

Simply put: Is it not possible to pass a function as the value of a CSS property in `$.animate()`?

Comment: as css properties do not get executed setting them to a function would be pointless

Comment: `this` is the `window` in that context. This doesn't answer your question, but you may just need to iterate: http://jsfiddle.net/544hs/

Comment: Hm, this is solved now, but there were a bunch of answers below, now missing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.div').each(function(){
  $(this).animate({width: $(this).data('foo')});
})
```

As for the functions - take a look at the "step" key of property hash - http://api.jquery.com/animate/